# List global array variables in a C program

Tags: c, code-analysis, ctags

There is a similar question asked before about listing global variables in C and the answers to that were using nm and ctags. ctags cli was -
ctags -R -x --sort=yes --c-kinds=v --file-scope=no

Is there a ctags option to list only global arrays. In a huge codebase we are trying to reduce memory footprint and need to analyze all global arrays. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use universal-ctags (https://ctags.io), readtags distributed as part of u-ctags may help you. The readtags command supports S-expression based filtering.

```
[yamato@slave]~/var/ctags-github% cat /tmp/a.c 
cat /tmp/a.c 
int f[10];
int g;
struct point {
  int x, y;
} points [64][32];
[yamato@slave]~/var/ctags-github% ./ctags --kinds-C=v --fields=+t /tmp/a.c 
./ctags --kinds-C=v --fields=+t /tmp/a.c 
[yamato@slave]~/var/ctags-github% cat tags 
cat tags 
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT   2   /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED   1   /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_OUTPUT_MODE   u-ctags /u-ctags or e-ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Universal Ctags Team    //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME  Universal Ctags /Derived from Exuberant Ctags/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL   https://ctags.io/   /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   0.0.0   /26a9333b/
f   /tmp/a.c    /^int f[10];$/;"    v   typeref:typename:int[10]
g   /tmp/a.c    /^int g;$/;"    v   typeref:typename:int
points  /tmp/a.c    /^} points [64][32];$/;"    v   typeref:struct:point[64][32]
[yamato@slave]~/var/ctags-github% ./readtags -t tags -e -Q '(substr? ($ "typeref") "[")' -l
./readtags -t tags -e -Q '(substr? ($ "typeref") "[")' -l
f   /tmp/a.c    /^int f[10];$/;"    kind:v  typeref:typename:int[10]
points  /tmp/a.c    /^} points [64][32];$/;"    kind:v  typeref:struct:point[64][32]
```